# How to make some nice photographs of midday sun?

Tags: composition, shooting-technique, sun, ideas

Can i get some ideas on how to photograph **midday sun** to make it **interesting**?

The fact why I ask this question is that photographing the midday sun alone gives a dumb photograph.

Only idea that comes to me is to play creatively with the **lens Flare**.So any-other ideas to add mood to this type of photos?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean taking general photos _around midday_ or actual photos of the midday Sun?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall actual photos of midday sun.. I was clear making it bold in the question though..

Comment: I was confused because it seems like a very odd thing to photograph, no to mention dangerous...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have a pretty girl with hardly any clothes on, say a beach volleyball uniform, and use the sun's flare to hide whether she has anything on. Have just a bit more light on the front than a silhouette. Let the flare shine in.